# HP 2920 Routing

Tags: layer3

I am working on setting up routing on a HP 2920 to a firewall. I can not figure out what I need to do to get this set up. I know that the *ip routing* command turns on routing and the *ip route*    command sets the route, but I don't know what address, subnet or gateway to use. Also, is there anything in particular I need to set my default gateway as on the switch itself?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

With `ip routing` in the config, the 2920 routes between all of its VLAN interfaces. For each VLAN, you need to configure an IP address, e.g. 10.0.99.1/24 on VLAN 99:

```
VLAN 99 ip address 10.0.99.1 255.255.255.0
```

Make sure you also either add remote routes statically (`ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.0.0.1` for a default route via 10.0.0.1) or run OSPF or RIP to learn the routes from the other routers.